# Google Sheets - Copying student rosters to new sheets based on column header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried searching in vain for an answer to this and hope I haven't missed anything. Apologies if this has been asked in the past, but here's where I'm stuck:

I'm creating a student data tracker for use by teachers. The idea is that they'll do a few minutes of setup where they enter their class names and student rosters, then click a button and the sheets get set using that data.

I have figured out how to run a script that copies a template and renames it based on the list of class names, but where I'm stuck is getting the roster to automatically copy with it.

The rosters are set as an array with two columns per class (first and last name) and the class names auto-populating above them in a merged column using index. The data is in cells G2:D50 (I have spacer columns for aesthetics for now, but could remove them if I need to). Since the sheets will inherit the class name that is shown above the student names, I figure there must be a way to say "Take the two columns that have 'xx' name above them and copy the data in rows 3-50 into this new sheet with the same name starting in row x"

I could always use an importrange or query, but want the data to be pasted as values automatically if possible.

Thanks very much!

Edit - [Here's a link to a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jEuXYem9a8qEac8V5yJJabDgVeZpl-8kiOu2FhCudCQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Great idea! Original post edited. [Here's a sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jEuXYem9a8qEac8V5yJJabDgVeZpl-8kiOu2FhCudCQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Few questions: Your student names in **start here** sheet are formatted as first name last name and in copied sheets(i.e. class1 to 7 sheets) it is last name first name, so do you want in that way only? Secondly, is columns containing student's names in the first sheet is going to remain in those alphabetically labelled columns only?(i.e. Class 1 names in G and H and so on) . Tip:- You can set IMPORTRANGE dynamically from script also.

Comment: Ultimately the names should probably be formatted Last/First so I'll make that change. The problem with using IMPORTRANGE is that I need the list of names to be sortable independent of the sorting on 'Start Here'. Teachers will need to be able to sort each class by name, or average score, or the score on a particular assessment. The simplest solution is obviously to have teachers just copy and paste the names in, but trying to automate as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed this in the sample file's script and removed where you set A7 to the formula:

```
          var studentRow = 4;
          var studentColumn = 7 + (i*3);
          var studentStartColumnName = NUM_RETURN_LETRA(studentColumn);
          var lastRow = getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray(studentStartColumnName) - 1;
          var studentEndColumnName = NUM_RETURN_LETRA(studentColumn + 1);
          var A1rangeString = studentStartColumnName + studentRow + ':' + studentEndColumnName + lastRow;
          var studentRange = studentsSheet.getRange(A1rangeString);

          //This will load the students into an Object.  You would push the students to a Range in the new sheet.activate
          var students = getRowsData(studentsSheet, studentRange);

          // It appears the students would be placed starting in cell A7 as Last Name and B7 as First Name
          var newRange = currentSheet.getRange("A7:B");
          var newValues = newRange.getValues();

          //Loop through all the read students and place them in the new location in the correct format
          for (s in students){
            newValues[s][0] = students[s].lastName;
            newValues[s][1] = students[s].firstName;
          }
          newRange.setValues(newValues);
```

I also added code in a second script file inside that for some utilities.  I named that file Utilities.gs.  This includes the getRowsData() function.

It should work out OK but may need a little editing to work in your exact situation.

Comment: This is great. You're a hero, and I really appreciate your help!